# Error executing groovy script that calls java static method returning a collection

Tags: java, logging, groovy

I am trying to execute the following groovy code in order to get the names of the active loggers I have in the application:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.*

loggers = LoggerContext.getLoggers()
loggers.toArray().each {
  println it
}
```

The script fails with this error:

```
Script execution has failed [reason: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.getLoggers() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Possible solutions: getLoggers(), getLogger(java.lang.String), getLogger(java.lang.String, org.apache.logging.log4j.message.MessageFactory), hasLogger(java.lang.String), hasLogger(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class), hasLogger(java.lang.String, org.apache.logging.log4j.message.MessageFactory)]
```

I tried to define the loggers variable with `Collection<Logger>` but the same error happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, there is no static `getLoggers()`. You need to get a `LoggerContext` instance first:

```
loggers = LoggerContext.getContext().getLoggers()
```

Comment: Duh, this is what happens when one does not pay attention. That was obvious, thanks for the facepalm!